# Calculate Peace-Years Variable

Tags: r, data-wrangling, panel-data

I have a typical panel dataset, structured via the time-variable `year` and the id-variable `fid`. I want to calculate the variable `peace_years` which captures the time in years, since the last violent event.

Here is a subset of my data, thank you for your help:

````
structure(list(year = c(2005L, 2006L, 2007L, 2008L, 2009L, 2005L, 
2006L, 2007L, 2008L, 2009L, 2005L, 2006L, 2007L, 2008L, 2009L, 
2005L, 2006L, 2007L, 2008L, 2009L, 2005L, 2006L, 2007L, 2008L, 
2009L, 2005L, 2006L, 2007L, 2008L, 2009L, 2005L, 2006L, 2007L, 
2008L, 2009L, 2005L, 2006L, 2007L, 2008L, 2009L, 2005L, 2006L, 
2007L, 2008L, 2009L, 2005L, 2006L, 2007L, 2008L, 2009L, 2005L, 
2006L, 2007L, 2008L, 2009L, 2005L, 2006L, 2007L, 2008L, 2009L, 
2005L, 2006L, 2007L, 2008L, 2009L, 2005L, 2006L, 2007L, 2008L, 
2009L, 2005L, 2006L, 2007L, 2008L, 2009L, 2005L, 2006L, 2007L, 
2008L, 2009L, 2005L, 2006L, 2007L, 2008L, 2009L, 2005L, 2006L, 
2007L, 2008L, 2009L, 2005L, 2006L, 2007L, 2008L, 2009L, 2005L, 
2006L, 2007L, 2008L, 2009L, 2005L, 2006L, 2007L, 2008L, 2009L, 
2005L, 2006L, 2007L, 2008L, 2009L, 2005L, 2006L, 2007L, 2008L, 
2009L, 2005L, 2006L, 2007L, 2008L, 2009L, 2005L, 2006L, 2007L, 
2008L, 2009L, 2005L, 2006L, 2007L, 2008L, 2009L, 2005L, 2006L, 
2007L, 2008L, 2009L, 2005L, 2006L, 2007L, 2008L, 2009L, 2005L, 
2006L, 2007L, 2008L, 2009L, 2005L, 2006L, 2007L, 2008L, 2009L, 
2005L, 2006L, 2007L, 2008L, 2009L, 2005L, 2006L, 2007L, 2008L, 
2009L, 2005L, 2006L, 2007L, 2008L, 2009L, 2005L, 2006L, 2007L, 
2008L, 2009L, 2005L, 2006L, 2007L, 2008L, 2009L, 2005L, 2006L, 
2007L, 2008L, 2009L, 2005L, 2006L, 2007L, 2008L, 2009L, 2005L, 
2006L, 2007L, 2008L, 2009L, 2005L, 2006L, 2007L, 2008L, 2009L, 
2005L, 2006L, 2007L, 2008L, 2009L, 2005L, 2006L, 2007L, 2008L, 
2009L, 2005L, 2006L, 2007L, 2008L, 2009L, 2005L, 2006L, 2007L, 
2008L, 2009L, 2005L, 2006L, 2007L, 2008L, 2009L, 2005L, 2006L, 
2007L, 2008L, 2009L, 2005L, 2006L, 2007L, 2008L, 2009L, 2005L, 
2006L, 2007L, 2008L, 2009L, 2005L, 2006L, 2007L, 2008L, 2009L, 
2005L, 2006L, 2007L, 2008L, 2009L, 2005L, 2006L, 2007L, 2008L, 
2009L, 2005L, 2006L, 2007L, 2008L, 2009L, 2005L, 2006L, 2007L, 
2008L, 2009L, 2005L, 2006L, 2007L, 2008L, 2009L, 2005L, 2006L, 
2007L, 2008L, 2009L, 2005L, 2006L, 2007L, 2008L, 2009L, 2005L, 
2006L, 2007L, 2008L, 2009L, 2005L, 2006L, 2007L, 2008L, 2009L, 
2005L, 2006L, 2007L, 2008L, 2009L, 2005L, 2006L, 2007L, 2008L, 
2009L, 2005L, 2006L, 2007L, 2008L, 2009L, 2005L, 2006L, 2007L, 
2008L, 2009L, 2005L, 2006L, 2007L, 2008L, 2009L, 2005L, 2006L, 
2007L, 2008L, 2009L, 2005L, 2006L, 2007L, 2008L, 2009L, 2005L, 
2006L, 2007L, 2008L, 2009L, 2005L, 2006L, 2007L, 2008L, 2009L, 
2005L, 2006L, 2007L, 2008L, 2009L, 2005L, 2006L, 2007L, 2008L, 
2009L, 2005L, 2006L, 2007L, 2008L, 2009L, 2005L, 2006L, 2007L, 
2008L, 2009L, 2005L, 2006L, 2007L, 2008L, 2009L, 2005L, 2006L, 
2007L, 2008L, 2009L, 2005L, 2006L, 2007L, 2008L, 2009L, 2005L, 
2006L, 2007L, 2008L, 2009L, 2005L, 2006L, 2007L, 2008L, 2009L, 
2005L, 2006L, 2007L, 2008L, 2009L, 2005L, 2006L, 2007L, 2008L, 
2009L, 2005L, 2006L, 2007L, 2008L, 2009L, 2005L, 2006L, 2007L, 
2008L, 2009L, 2005L, 2006L, 2007L, 2008L, 2009L, 2005L, 2006L, 
2007L, 2008L, 2009L, 2005L, 2006L, 2007L, 2008L, 2009L, 2005L, 
2006L, 2007L, 2008L, 2009L, 2005L, 2006L, 2007L, 2008L, 2009L, 
2005L, 2006L, 2007L, 2008L, 2009L, 2005L, 2006L, 2007L, 2008L, 
2009L, 2005L, 2006L, 2007L, 2008L, 2009L, 2005L, 2006L, 2007L, 
2008L, 2009L, 2005L, 2006L, 2007L, 2008L, 2009L, 2005L, 2006L, 
2007L, 2008L, 2009L, 2005L, 2006L, 2007L, 2008L, 2009L, 2005L, 
2006L, 2007L, 2008L, 2009L, 2005L, 2006L, 2007L, 2008L, 2009L, 
2005L, 2006L, 2007L, 2008L, 2009L, 2005L, 2006L, 2007L, 2008L, 
2009L, 2005L, 2006L, 2007L, 2008L, 2009L, 2005L, 2006L, 2007L, 
2008L, 2009L, 2005L, 2006L, 2007L, 2008L, 2009L, 2005L, 2006L, 
2007L, 2008L, 2009L, 2005L, 2006L, 2007L, 2008L, 2009L, 2005L, 
2006L, 2007L, 2008L, 2009L, 2005L, 2006L, 2007L, 2008L, 2009L, 
2005L, 2006L, 2007L, 2008L, 2009L, 2005L, 2006L, 2007L, 2008L, 
2009L, 2005L, 2006L, 2007L, 2008L, 2009L, 2005L, 2006L, 2007L, 
2008L, 2009L, 2005L, 2006L, 2007L, 2008L, 2009L, 2005L, 2006L, 
2007L, 2008L, 2009L, 2005L, 2006L, 2007L, 2008L, 2009L, 2005L, 
2006L, 2007L, 2008L, 2009L, 2005L, 2006L, 2007L, 2008L, 2009L, 
2005L, 2006L, 2007L, 2008L, 2009L, 2005L, 2006L, 2007L, 2008L, 
2009L, 2005L, 2006L, 2007L, 2008L, 2009L, 2005L, 2006L, 2007L, 
2008L, 2009L, 2005L, 2006L, 2007L, 2008L, 2009L, 2005L, 2006L, 
2007L, 2008L, 2009L, 2005L, 2006L, 2007L, 2008L, 2009L, 2005L, 
2006L, 2007L, 2008L, 2009L, 2005L, 2006L, 2007L, 2008L, 2009L, 
2005L, 2006L, 2007L, 2008L, 2009L, 2005L, 2006L, 2007L, 2008L, 
2009L, 2005L, 2006L, 2007L, 2008L, 2009L, 2005L, 2006L, 2007L, 
2008L, 2009L, 2005L, 2006L, 2007L, 2008L, 2009L, 2005L, 2006L, 
2007L, 2008L, 2009L, 2005L, 2006L, 2007L, 2008L, 2009L, 2005L, 
2006L, 2007L, 2008L, 2009L, 2005L, 2006L, 2007L, 2008L, 2009L, 
2005L, 2006L, 2007L, 2008L, 2009L, 2005L, 2006L, 2007L, 2008L, 
2009L, 2005L, 2006L, 2007L, 2008L, 2009L, 2005L, 2006L, 2007L, 
2008L, 2009L, 2005L, 2006L, 2007L, 2008L, 2009L, 2005L, 2006L, 
2007L, 2008L, 2009L, 2005L, 2006L, 2007L, 2008L, 2009L, 2005L, 
2006L, 2007L, 2008L, 2009L, 2005L, 2006L, 2007L, 2008L, 2009L, 
2005L, 2006L, 2007L, 2008L, 2009L, 2005L, 2006L, 2007L, 2008L, 
2009L), fid = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 
6L, 6L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 
9L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 12L, 12L, 
12L, 12L, 12L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 
15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 
17L, 17L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 20L, 
20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 21L, 21L, 21L, 21L, 21L, 22L, 22L, 22L, 22L, 
22L, 23L, 23L, 23L, 23L, 23L, 24L, 24L, 24L, 24L, 24L, 25L, 25L, 
25L, 25L, 25L, 26L, 26L, 26L, 26L, 26L, 27L, 27L, 27L, 27L, 27L, 
28L, 28L, 28L, 28L, 28L, 29L, 29L, 29L, 29L, 29L, 30L, 30L, 30L, 
30L, 30L, 31L, 31L, 31L, 31L, 31L, 32L, 32L, 32L, 32L, 32L, 33L, 
33L, 33L, 33L, 33L, 34L, 34L, 34L, 34L, 34L, 35L, 35L, 35L, 35L, 
35L, 36L, 36L, 36L, 36L, 36L, 37L, 37L, 37L, 37L, 37L, 38L, 38L, 
38L, 38L, 38L, 39L, 39L, 39L, 39L, 39L, 40L, 40L, 40L, 40L, 40L, 
41L, 41L, 41L, 41L, 41L, 42L, 42L, 42L, 42L, 42L, 43L, 43L, 43L, 
43L, 43L, 44L, 44L, 44L, 44L, 44L, 45L, 45L, 45L, 45L, 45L, 46L, 
46L, 46L, 46L, 46L, 47L, 47L, 47L, 47L, 47L, 48L, 48L, 48L, 48L, 
48L, 49L, 49L, 49L, 49L, 49L, 50L, 50L, 50L, 50L, 50L, 51L, 51L, 
51L, 51L, 51L, 52L, 52L, 52L, 52L, 52L, 53L, 53L, 53L, 53L, 53L, 
54L, 54L, 54L, 54L, 54L, 55L, 55L, 55L, 55L, 55L, 56L, 56L, 56L, 
56L, 56L, 57L, 57L, 57L, 57L, 57L, 58L, 58L, 58L, 58L, 58L, 59L, 
59L, 59L, 59L, 59L, 60L, 60L, 60L, 60L, 60L, 61L, 61L, 61L, 61L, 
61L, 62L, 62L, 62L, 62L, 62L, 63L, 63L, 63L, 63L, 63L, 64L, 64L, 
64L, 64L, 64L, 65L, 65L, 65L, 65L, 65L, 66L, 66L, 66L, 66L, 66L, 
67L, 67L, 67L, 67L, 67L, 68L, 68L, 68L, 68L, 68L, 69L, 69L, 69L, 
69L, 69L, 70L, 70L, 70L, 70L, 70L, 71L, 71L, 71L, 71L, 71L, 72L, 
72L, 72L, 72L, 72L, 73L, 73L, 73L, 73L, 73L, 74L, 74L, 74L, 74L, 
74L, 75L, 75L, 75L, 75L, 75L, 76L, 76L, 76L, 76L, 76L, 77L, 77L, 
77L, 77L, 77L, 78L, 78L, 78L, 78L, 78L, 79L, 79L, 79L, 79L, 79L, 
80L, 80L, 80L, 80L, 80L, 81L, 81L, 81L, 81L, 81L, 82L, 82L, 82L, 
82L, 82L, 83L, 83L, 83L, 83L, 83L, 84L, 84L, 84L, 84L, 84L, 85L, 
85L, 85L, 85L, 85L, 86L, 86L, 86L, 86L, 86L, 87L, 87L, 87L, 87L, 
87L, 88L, 88L, 88L, 88L, 88L, 89L, 89L, 89L, 89L, 89L, 90L, 90L, 
90L, 90L, 90L, 91L, 91L, 91L, 91L, 91L, 92L, 92L, 92L, 92L, 92L, 
93L, 93L, 93L, 93L, 93L, 94L, 94L, 94L, 94L, 94L, 95L, 95L, 95L, 
95L, 95L, 96L, 96L, 96L, 96L, 96L, 97L, 97L, 97L, 97L, 97L, 98L, 
98L, 98L, 98L, 98L, 99L, 99L, 99L, 99L, 99L, 100L, 100L, 100L, 
100L, 100L, 101L, 101L, 101L, 101L, 101L, 102L, 102L, 102L, 102L, 
102L, 103L, 103L, 103L, 103L, 103L, 104L, 104L, 104L, 104L, 104L, 
105L, 105L, 105L, 105L, 105L, 106L, 106L, 106L, 106L, 106L, 107L, 
107L, 107L, 107L, 107L, 108L, 108L, 108L, 108L, 108L, 109L, 109L, 
109L, 109L, 109L, 110L, 110L, 110L, 110L, 110L, 111L, 111L, 111L, 
111L, 111L, 112L, 112L, 112L, 112L, 112L, 113L, 113L, 113L, 113L, 
113L, 114L, 114L, 114L, 114L, 114L, 115L, 115L, 115L, 115L, 115L, 
116L, 116L, 116L, 116L, 116L, 117L, 117L, 117L, 117L, 117L, 118L, 
118L, 118L, 118L, 118L, 119L, 119L, 119L, 119L, 119L, 120L, 120L, 
120L, 120L, 120L, 121L, 121L, 121L, 121L, 121L, 122L, 122L, 122L, 
122L, 122L, 123L, 123L, 123L, 123L, 123L, 124L, 124L, 124L, 124L, 
124L, 125L, 125L, 125L, 125L, 125L, 126L, 126L, 126L, 126L, 126L, 
127L, 127L, 127L, 127L, 127L, 128L, 128L, 128L, 128L, 128L, 129L, 
129L, 129L, 129L, 129L, 130L, 130L, 130L, 130L, 130L, 131L, 131L, 
131L, 131L, 131L, 132L, 132L, 132L, 132L, 132L, 133L, 133L, 133L, 
133L, 133L, 134L, 134L, 134L, 134L, 134L, 135L, 135L, 135L, 135L, 
135L, 136L, 136L, 136L, 136L, 136L, 137L, 137L, 137L, 137L, 137L, 
138L, 138L, 138L, 138L, 138L, 139L, 139L, 139L, 139L, 139L, 140L, 
140L, 140L, 140L, 140L), violent_ev_sum = c(7L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 4L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 2L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 3L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 5L, 6L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 19L, 4L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 4L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 11L, 
10L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 29L, 11L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 8L, 2L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 2L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 13L, 4L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 53L, 10L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 4L, 4L, 0L, 2L, 2L, 0L, 0L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 3L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
3L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 2L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 2L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 2L, 0L, 2L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 15L, 2L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 41L, 28L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L)), row.names = c(NA, 
700L), class = "data.frame") ```
````

Comment: What have you tried, so far?

Comment: Does this dataframe suffice to reproduce your question: `data.frame(year = rep(2005:2007, 2), fid = gl(2, 3), violent_ev_sum = c(1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 7))` ? If so, please edit you question towards a *minimal* reproducible example and specify the role of `fid` in your question: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Care to provide a small set of expected results?

Answer (score 0):

In this solution, the `peace_years` variable is calculated by subtracting the most recent year with a positive number of `violent_ev_sum` from the current year.

```r
library(tidyverse)

dat %>%
  group_by(fid) %>%
  filter(violent_ev_sum > 0) %>%
  summarize(peace_years = year(Sys.time()) - max(year))
#> # A tibble: 39 × 2
#>      fid peace_years
#>    <int>       <dbl>
#>  1     1          17
#>  2     2          17
#>  3     4          17
#>  4     5          18
#>  5    14          16
#>  6    15          16
#>  7    22          17
#>  8    23          18
#>  9    24          16
#> 10    25          17
#> # ℹ 29 more rows
```

<sup>Created on 2023-05-23 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: I receive: Caused by error in `year()`:
! could not find function "year"

Comment: `year()` is from the `lubridate` package. If you're using an older version of `tidyverse` you'll need to attach this package (`library(lubridate)`)